# flatMap writeValue for characteristic do not return Observable

Tags: swift, bluetooth, rx-swift, ios-bluetooth, rxiosble

*Update:* I just checked their example projects and it is the same. So, it might be a bug, or this is expected behaviour.

I'm using RxBluetoothKit and cannot figure out the following issue. I'm having this wrapper function to write a characteristics (I'm trying to write many of them with concat, it works nice):

```
func writeCharacteristicData(for peripheral: Peripheral, characteristicIdentifier: CharacteristicIdentifier, value: Data?) -> Observable<Characteristic> {
guard let value = value else {
  return Observable.error(BTError.noDataProvided(description: "Missing value for: \(characteristicIdentifier)"))
}
return peripheral
  .connect()
  .flatMap { $0.writeValue(value,
    for: characteristicIdentifier,
    type: .withResponse) }
}
```

According to RxBluetoothKit documentation `.flatMap { $0.writeValue }` is one of the easiest way to write in a characteristic. Actually it works just fine with `readValue` and even with this `writeValue`, the write is successful, and if I read it back with readValue after that, the `characteristic.value` is OK in `oNext:`.

My problem is that this function returns an `Observable<Characteristic>` and my assumption was that it will give me back the written value. But that's not the case, or at least it does not work for me. It gives me back previous values or nil, I could not figure this out so far what's the logic on the emitted `Observable<Characteristic>`. It would be really nice if I can get back the written value. What am I doing wrong?

I even tried the longer ways, and this one, mentioned on github:

```
characteristic.writeValue(data, type: .withResponse)
.subscribe { event in
    //respond to errors / successful read
}
```

The emitted characteristic (in the `onNext:` callback) is not the one I wrote to the device. It's a previous one or nil. The funny thing is if I try to read it back, and write after that, the characteristic.value will be the one that I've read with `$0.readValue`. But if I recompile, write a completely new one, it's still the same I've read before. It's like RxBluetoothKit cached a value or I have no idea whatsoever.

Can this be a problem with the ble device? 
Maybe it's a thread issue or something like that?

I'd really appreciate any kind of advice or hints.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of response, I've just noticed this. Does your problem still occur? If so - please write an issue on our Github. It's connected to how Core Bluetooth itself works and we maybe should improve our documentation, so it would be good to have it as an issue. What you should do is to read the value again - it'll then show the correct value.